# React build - Reference error: Window is not Defined - How to only run on client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, build, gatsby, netlify

I've got a `p5.js` sketch that is included in my `gatsby.js` project. When I push and build my project on `netlify.com` it thows:

- `error "window" is not available during server side rendering.`
- on: `window.requestAnimationFrame = (function() {`
- `WebpackError: ReferenceError: window is not defined`

Ok, I understand why. During the build the window DOM is not available. So I tried to work around it with two ways, as seen in my code example.

- First is to use react [loadable componant](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components)
- Second to check if `window` is undefined (on build) and if so return something else than the main code.

my code example:

```
  import loadable from '@loadable/component'
  import sketch from "./p5_app";
  
  class GetP5Wrapper extends React.Component {
    render() {
  
      if (typeof window === 'undefined') 
         return <span>loading...</span>
  
      const P5Wrapper = loadable(() => import('react-p5-wrapper'))  //loadable help is not to run on build
  
      return <P5Wrapper sketch={sketch}/>
    }
  }
```

## the question:

How do I get my sketch to only run on client side.

Comment: are you getting the error even with the tricks? does ./p5_app have code that uses window?

Comment: @diedu :) Yes, I've just figured it out yesterday... the `./p5_app` also used `window` indeed :) I've moved the import into the window check. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out. I've switched from [react-p5-wrapper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5-wrapper) to [react-p5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-p5). It kept giving problems, even with the solution. So I switched. Also I've moved the check if window exists into the component. Which is much cleaner

```
  render() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {

      const Sketch = loadable(() => import('react-p5'));

      return <Sketch setup={this.setup} draw={this.draw}/>

    } else { // if window does not exist

      return null;
    }
  }
```