# Problem with componentDidMount and Docusaurus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, docusaurus

Currently, I am building a react app with Docusaurus and I am having a problem building the app. The error message says:

```
[0] [ERROR] Docusaurus Node/SSR could not render static page with path /adminTools because of following error:
[0] ReferenceError: window is not defined
[0]     at Object.50671 (main:136486:44)
[0]     at __webpack_require__ (main:224909:42)
[0]     at Object.389 (main:136493:18)
[0]     at __webpack_require__ (main:224909:42)
[0]     at Module.95191 (main:58341:32)
[0]     at __webpack_require__ (main:224909:42)
[0]     at main:12784:4156
[0] [INFO] It looks like you are using code that should run on the client-side only.
[0] To get around it, try using `<BrowserOnly>` (https://docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus-core/#browseronly) or `ExecutionEnvironment` (https://docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus-core/#executionenvironment).
[0] It might also require to wrap your client code in `useEffect` hook and/or import a third-party library dynamically (if any).
[0] ✔ Server: Compiled with some errors in 28.91s
[0] 
[0] 
[0] Error: Server-side rendering fails due to the error above.
```

I believe this is a problem with my adminTools components, as I use axios requests within them to update state in my componentDidMount function. I believe this is wrong, and am unsure of why and was hoping someone could help me solve this! I am not 100% with lifecycle, which is why I am asking for some sort of clarification as to what I am doing wrong.

This might also be a webpack issue, but again I am unsure.

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it! After some looking, I stumbled upon this overflow post: [React build - Reference error: Window is not Defined - How to only run on client side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60419263/react-build-reference-error-window-is-not-defined-how-to-only-run-on-client)

This person had a similar issue, and I found that by using loadable((), I was able to fix the problem.

Check out their docs! [Loadable Docs](https://github.com/gregberge/loadable-components)

Answer (score 0):

```
componentWillUnmount() {
   if(typeof window !== 'undefined'){
      window.location.reload();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Tried this but didn't work. Here is part of the error too: "[INFO] It looks like you are using code that should run on the client-side only.
[0] To get around it, try using `<BrowserOnly>` (https://docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus-core/#browseronly) or `ExecutionEnvironment` (https://docusaurus.io/docs/docusaurus-core/#executionenvironment).
[0] It might also require to wrap your client code in `useEffect` hook and/or import a third-party library dynamically (if any).
[0] ✔ Server: Compiled with some errors in 28.62s"

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of this issue in both dev and build you should add the condition
`if (typeof window !== "undefined")` in the `Root` component

> The  component is rendered at the very top of the React tree, above the theme , and never unmounts. It is the perfect place to add stateful logic that should not be re-initialized across navigations (user authentication status, shopping cart state...). Read [this](https://docusaurus.io/docs/swizzling#wrapper-your-site-with-root) for more detail.

So create Root.js under src/theme and add the logic here :

src/theme/Root.js

```js
import React from "react";
export default function Root({ children }) {
  if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
    return (
      <>
        {children}
      </>
    );
  }
  return null;
}
```

Like this will get rid from this issue definitively